# Camera customization sencha touch

Tags: extjs, camera, sencha-touch, customization

I'm using the `Ext.device.Camera` component to take photos in my sencha touch app. I'd like to change some things of this component:

1. Change the text of the buttons **retake** and **use**
2. Add a button to show the camera roll (The camera roll view is ready, so the button will only change the view)
3. After the call at success function I would like that the camera won't close and it gives the possibility to the user to take another photo

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that from ST2. That's native stuff, if you are wrapping with [phonegap/cordova](http://phonegap.com/) you could create a [custom plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide).